# How to get data from a array than have other array inside

Tags: javascript

I would like to run a function where the user has the option to choose some of the characters in the "characters" array, and then allows the user to choose some of the objects inside this character (jLP, sLP or cLP) and get the information from that object. I tried using the "find" function for this, but I couldn't find any way to do it for this specific use. What i need to do to obtain these specific infos?

My infos:

```js
...
var characters = [parasoul, fukua]
var parasoul = {p: "jLP", dmg: 220, type: "jumping"}, {p: "sLP", dmg: 110, type: "standing"}, {p: "cLP", dmg: 10, type: "crounching"}
var fukua = {p: "jLP", dmg: 50, type: "jumping"}, {p: "sLP", dmg: 160, type: "standing"}, {p: "cLP", dmg: 20, type: "crounching"}
...
```

Comment: What did you try? How do you ideally want the output? How are you taking user input? — Please try and use code to answer these questions as it helps give structure to the answers you recieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the way you've written `parasoul` and `fukua` does not make sense. I think you're trying to write an array of objects, but that requires the objects to be wrapped in brackets `[]`.

Second, if you want to quickly search those lists for the "p" property, you'll find your program runs faster if you use an object instead, like shown here:

```
var parasoul = {
  jLP: {
    dmg: 220,
    type: "jumping"
  },
  sLP: {
    dmg: 110,
    type: "standing"
  },
  cLP: {
    dmg: 10,
    type: "crounching"
  }
};

var characters = {
  parasoul: {...parasoul} // put a copy of the parasoul object inside the characters object
};
```

You can then access those values in two ways: `parasoul.jLP` or `parasoul["jLP"]`

This allows you to use user input to access the values like this:

```
var userInputCharacter = getUserInput(); // this is not a real function, just an example.
var userCharacter = characters[userInputCharacter]; // if user input is "parasoul" then userCharacter is the parasoul object
```

I hope this helps, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: It helped a lot! I'm using this stuff in a discord bot. The objective is to save the information of these buttons, (jLP, sLP and cLP are buttons in a fighting game) allowing the user to access them at any time. In case, if he wants the parasoul character's jLP button, he can get it with a command, so I wanted to know how to perform this specific path. But this solution of yours explained to me what I wanted to find, sorry for the question not being clear!

Comment: You're welcome! If you think your question is answered then please mark the solution. Otherwise, feel free to edit your question with updates, or ask for more information here, in the comments.